# My socket wont change from server address to host

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Im struggling to change this segment from requiring a server address hard coded to using

`private static inetAddress host;`

Here is the code

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ChatClient extends JFrame {

    private JFrame chatFrame = new JFrame("Welcome To The Chat Room");
    private JFrame loginFrame;
    private JButton sendBtn, exitBtn;
    private JTextField typingArea;
    private JTextArea inRoom;
    private JTextArea chatBox;
    private JTextField loginInput;
    private static String username, entry;
    private static InetAddress host;

    public static ArrayList<String> usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    BufferedReader networkInput;
    PrintWriter networkOutput;

    public void loginDisplay() throws Exception {

        chatFrame.setVisible(false);
        loginFrame = new JFrame("Welcome User!");
        loginInput = new JTextField(15);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Pick a username:");
        JButton joinServer = new JButton("Enter Chat Server");

        joinServer.addActionListener(new loginBtnClick());
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();


        loginPanel.add(usernameLabel);
        loginPanel.add(loginInput);

        loginFrame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, loginPanel);
        loginFrame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, joinServer);
        loginFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void display() throws IOException {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        typingArea = new JTextField(40);

        sendBtn = new JButton("Send Your Message");
        sendBtn.addActionListener(new sendBtnClick());

        chatBox = new JTextArea();
        chatBox.setEditable(false);
        chatBox.setLineWrap(true);

        inRoom = new JTextArea();
        inRoom.setEditable(false);
        inRoom.setLineWrap(false);
        inRoom.setSize(150, 300);

        inRoom.append("Users in Room: \n");

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(chatBox));
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(inRoom), BorderLayout.WEST);

        southPanel.add(typingArea);
        southPanel.add(sendBtn);

        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);
        chatFrame.add(mainPanel);
        chatFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        chatFrame.setSize(470, 350);
        chatFrame.setVisible(true);
        //chatFrame.setResizable(false);
    }

    //private String getServerAddress() {
    //  return "127.0.0.1";
    //}

    private class loginBtnClick implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            username = loginInput.getText();
            if (username.length() < 1) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username");
                //message to server and user error username

            } else {
                loginFrame.setVisible(false);
                networkOutput.println(loginInput.getText());
                try {
                    display();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private class sendBtnClick implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (typingArea.getText().length() < 1) {

            } else {
                networkOutput.println(typingArea.getText());
                typingArea.setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() throws IOException {

        //String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, 1237);
        networkInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        networkOutput = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while (true) {
            String line = networkInput.readLine();

            if (line.startsWith("NAMESENT  ")) {
                if (username != null) {
                    networkOutput.println(username);
                }
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {

            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                chatBox.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");

            } else if (line.startsWith("LIST")) {
                if (!usersList.contains(line.substring(5))) {
                    usersList.add(line.substring(5));
                    inRoom.append(line.substring(5) + "\n");
                }
            } else if (line.startsWith("SPECMSG")) {
                if (line.substring(8).startsWith(username)) {
                    chatBox.append(line.substring(9 + username.length()));
                }
            } else if (line.startsWith("DISCONNECT")) {
                chatBox.append(line.substring(10) + " has disconnected.");
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ChatClient chat = new ChatClient();
        try {
            chat.loginDisplay();
            chat.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

In the past i have had it as simple as this but i cant get it to be happy with it

```
private static void sendMessages() 
                            throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final int PORT = 1239;
    String entry;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
```

EDIT

I want to get the top code to not say

```
socket = new Socket(ServerAddress, 1237)
```

i want it to say

```
socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
```

EDIT 2

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ChatClient$loginBtnClick.actionPerformed(ChatClient.java:106)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, could you please clarify what's wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: This constructor exists https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int) so please be more accurate in your question

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ChatClient$loginBtnClick.actionPerformed(ChatClient.java:106)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: add this in your question with the code of ChatClient

Comment: is there a way i can message you so i can state this more clearly?

Comment: Why can't you just put the info in your question, to let people help you?

Comment: theres a time frame for editing questions isnt there? or is that only for this comment part down here. that was my worry i didnt want to run out of time editing, i do apologise

Comment: no you can edit it as many times as you want

Comment: it must be the comments here with the time limit (im sure it has happened to me before)
i have updated it now

Comment: yes it is with the comment, you have a limited time to edit it but it is not applicable to questions hopefully some questions are edited even years later

Comment: that was asked by someone else not me, i understand how the null pointers work and the exceptions but sometimes you just cannot see where you need to put them. that is the case here it seems

Comment: i have an error on an exact line that is not helped by the person killing my question, why does 106 have an error? where should the null pointer be?
and i didnt want to dump my entire code because it causes issues with people stealing it which i have ran into

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 documentation 
[Socket Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) says that it's possible to define a socket with

Socket(String host, int port)

*Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number on the named host.*

Maybe you're problem is that the host OR the port at which you're connecting are down.

Comment: whaoo we don't understand the question and you have already an answer, very impressive!

Comment: trying to help, whether possible

Comment: i still dont understand, can you show me on my code where the nullptr should be? the question has been murdered and ive been linked to 'help' which does not help